# Removing and adding Ints from a list based on another list

Tags: list, kotlin

```
Kotlin 1.4.72
```

I have a list of Ints called `listOfSelectedIds`

Another list will be generated called `currentIds`.

I want to be able to add or remove from the `listOfSelectedIds` based on the following condition:

If there is a ID from the `currentIds` that exists in the `listOfSelectedIds` then that ID should be removed from the `listOfSelectedIds`. Else if the ID does not exist then it should be added to the `listOfSelectedids`.

Is there any operators that do this on a list.

Example

```
listOfSelectedIds [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
listOfCurrentIds [4, 5, 6, 7]
```

So the end result of listOfSelectedIds will be `[1, 2, 3, 6, 7]`
4 and 5 have been removed. And 6 and 7 has been added.

Many thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also do this in one iteration

```
fun main() {
    val selectedIds = setOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) // Set A
    val currentIds = setOf(4, 5, 6, 7) // Set B

    println(selectedIds.xor(currentIds))
}


fun <T> Set<T>.xor(b: Set<T>): Set<T> {
    val mutableB = b.toMutableSet()
    return filterNot { mutableB.remove(it) } union mutableB
}
```

Comment: This is a good solution! Essentailly, it boils down to an XOR like operation.

Answer (score 3):

You can change your list to a `Set` and perform set operations. From a mathematical standpoint, it will be `(A-B) U (B-A)`.

1. Subtract B from A, and A from B.
2. Do a union of the two sets generated from step 1.

   ```
   fun main() {
       val selectedIds = setOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) // Set A
       val currentIds = setOf(4, 5, 6, 7) // Set B
       val selectedIdsNotInCurrentIds = selectedIds subtract currentIds // Set A-B
       val currentIdsNotInSelectedIds = currentIds subtract selectedIds // Set B-A
       val result = selectedIdsNotInCurrentIds union currentIdsNotInSelectedIds // (A-B) U (B-A)
       println(result)
   }
   ```